# Magento: Googlebot trying to access invalid URLs due to the addition of a trailing slash

Tags: magento, googlebot

For some reason when googlebot spiders my Magento store it regularly generates debug reports due to a mistakenly added trailing slash to URLs containing arguments, such as:

```
http://www.sinfulthrills.co.uk/lingerie-clothing-1/sexy-lingerie?filter_brand=14054&filter_size=13258/.
```

Here’s the first few lines of the latest store debug report:

```
URL: http://www.sinfulthrills.co.uk/lingerie-clothing-1/sexy-lingerie?filter_brand=14054&filter_size=13258/
IP Address: 66.249.72.177
Time: 2012-08-22 12:39:58 GMT
Error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `filter_brand_idx` ON filter_brand_' at line 4
```

Now I’m certain that there is not a single link on my site that contains the trailing slash so how could it be possible that Google is mistakenly adding one?  I’m worried that these invalid URLs will be negatively affecting my index positioning :(

I should add that it’s not always the same filtering arguments or argument values that are being used when this happens, nor is it the same product category. There is no pattern that I’ve been able to spot.

Comment: You should block those filters with robots.txt and it will help increase the efficiency of your google crawls, and it's also good for SEO...

Comment: Actually that's a good point utility - these filters ARE actually turned off in my crawl settings in Webmaster tools, however googlebot is still crawling them and it's doing it incorrectly to boot...

Comment: Naughty google... they never seem to follow those url parameters..

Comment: I've updated my robots.txt to reflect the settings I already had in Google Webmaster Tools' URL Parameters tab but I am still seeing these debug reports regularly.  Is there anything I could do to investigate why this trailing slash is being added to the URLs so that at least no errors are being reported?  Any help is gratefully received as I really don't know where to start looking with this.

Comment: What do your rewrites rules look like in htaccess?

Comment: Complex! Here's a Google docs copy of the rewrite section:    https://docs.google.com/document/d/19tCQPJ_aXx-mibPxgNW_5zCAc4flA9iTO6Y7UA4X7lI/edit

Comment: Yep - here you go http://pastebin.com/Mb35epsn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google appears to have finally settled down and is now taking notice of the filters I had set - I haven't had an error in quite a few weeks now.  I'd give Utility the points for answering this question if he'd actually answered it haha...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've submitted this URL in your sitemap?

Also if this is a 404 link you can probably back track it with Google Webmaster Tools (in Crawl Error list it will provide the linking page)

GL

Comment: Igal these URLs are different every time so it's not a case of the wrong URL having been submitted.